# --var() в Brackets (CSS)

Tags: css, brackets

Как при написании кода в Brackets вывести подсказки при использовании кода.

```
:root {
--color:#000;
}
        
.name {
color: --var(color);
}
```

Что при написании color: --var(тут список заданых в root) - появлялась подсказка

Comment: Нужно `color: var(--color)`